# How to use whereIn and where in laravel query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a collection and on which I want to use whereIn and where but I know whereIn or where can work.

I want to get results where user ids = [1,2,3,4] and type = admin. If user id is blank then show post of admin and if type = admin is null then show post on the base of user ids or if both are available then show all the posts having user ids and admin type.

here is my query :

```php
Post::with('commonContent', 'postLike','user.userDetails','likeCount')
    ->whereIn('user_id',$user_ids)
    ->where('type','admin');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want like this?

```
Post::with('commonContent', 'postLike','user.userDetails','likeCount')->whereIn('user_id',$user_ids)->orWhere('type','admin')->get();
```